# Differentiating between assignment and expression in LL(1) grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf

I'm writing a grammar for a simple programming language in LL(1) form.

For expressions I have the following

```
<expression> ::= 
  <term> “+” <expression> 
| <term> “-” <expression> 
| <term>

<term> ::=
  <factor> “*” <expression> 
| <factor> “/” <expression>
| <factor>

<factor> ::= 
“(” <expression> “)”
| id
| num
```

And for assignments I have

```
<assignment> ::= id “=“ <expression>
```

As I understand it this isn't LL(1) form since an ID on the left side could mean either an expression or an assignment and I would need an additional lookahead in order to determine which.

How could I rewrite this so that it's in LL(1) form?

Answer (score 0):

You only show part of the grammar, but unless you allow free-standing expressions as valid statements you shouldn't have any ambiguity in what you show.

If you do allow free-standing expressions as statements, you could define the grammar for assignment like this:

```
<assignment>  ::= <expression> <assignment2>
<assignment2> ::= "=" <expression>
                  | E
```

and then let the semantic analysis phase determine if the first expression is a valid *lvalue*. This would probably be a *good thing* to do because it potentially allows assignment to things more complex than a mere identifier, e.g. an array expression or a de-referenced pointer.

Comment: I think that I should allow for free-standing expressions considering that you should be able to call a function like func(x+y) where x+y is a free-standing expression. I'm not sure that your answer would work though. Consider that I have a <statement> non-terminal that includes <expression> and <assignment>. Checking <assignment> first and then finding out that the operator is "+" would mean that I would have to backtrack and then check for <expression> instead. Also writing 5=4 in for example C is syntactically incorrect if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified that. Please see my edit, though what I suggest there is probably still a gross simplification over what C would require. Yes, you are correct, of course, that `5=4` is a perfectly valid C statement. C is weird that way :)

Comment: Incidentally I don't believe it's possible to write an LL(1) grammar for C.